# Getter function not returning value when accessed from another class

Tags: java, android

I have a class as follows:

```
public class Element extends Activity
{
public float mX;
    public float mY;
 public void animate(long elapsedTime) 
    {
        mX += mSpeedX * (elapsedTime / 20f);
        mY += mSpeedY * (elapsedTime / 20f);
        setmX(mX);
        setmY(mY);
        checkBorders();
    }
public void setmX(float mX) 
{
Log.i("this.mX","mY at setmX read is :"+this.mX );      **//Line 1**
        this.mX = mX;
    }
public float getmX() {
        Log.i("mX","mX in getmX read is :"+mX );    **//Line 2**
        return mX;
    }

    public void setmY(float mY) {

        this.mY = mY;
        Log.i("this.mY","mY at setmY read is :"+this.mY );  **//Line 3**
    }

    public float getmY() {
        Log.i("mY","mY in getY read is :"+mY );    **//Line 4**

        return mY;
    }
}
```

I have another class

```
public class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
int x = 100;
    int y = 0;
public float xval;
    public float yval; 
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        Element element = new Element();
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        Log.i("x","x in panel is :"+x);
        //toast tos = new toast();

        xval = element.getmX();
        Log.i("xval","xval in playactivity obtained is :"+xval );   **//Line 5**
        yval = element.getmY();
        Log.i("yval","yval in playactivity obtained is :"+xval );    **//Line 6**
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Lines 2, 4, 5, and 6 are showing values as zero. Which I don't want to. Below is the logcat image.
[image]

**Have I made error in the access Specifiers?**

Comment: You can actually copy/paste the logs. Select the rows you want and hit Ctrl + C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should not create an object of Activity class (in you class Element class) in another class. Please go through the [Application fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)
- Though you are creating an object of `Element` class in the `Panel` class, you never called setter method setmX() and setmY() to set the values. You are directly calling the getter methods which returns you the default values.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for us to tell what's going on without knowing `mSpeedX` and `mSpeedY`. Try casting both `elapsedTime` and your `mSpeedX/Y` variables to floats before doing the math. Floating point math is pretty picky in Java. Also ensure that the `animate` method is actually being called.

One final note, I probably shouldn't bring this up but it's killing me. You should **really, really** work on your code consistency and style. Your naming conventions, newline/sameline brace conventions, and indentation habits are all over the place. Code readability and maintainability go down dramatically if your programming style is not **consistent**.

One more thing: you don't need to call the setter methods after assigning values to a variable. You've already set the value of the very same variable that your set/get methods are accessing. Good luck!